# How do you tell what model of bike I have?

Tags: road-bike, frames, saddle, steel

I bought this bike 2 days ago. I searched for some info, but couldn't find it. The only information I found was to be around 1972

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I initially removed the mountain bike tag because it's a Merckx, eponymously named after Eddy Merckx, who made his name racing road and I am pretty sure his line of bikes didn't include MTBs. At least, the color and the decals suggest a Merckx - the decal on the down tube looks a bit roughly done and I wonder if it's possibly fake.

Comment: Certainly no earlier than 1972, but likely some time in the 70s or 80s.  The handlebar may have been replaced.

Comment: Such a nice bike with such ugly handlebars.

Comment: At the very least have the brakes and brake cables serviced. The pads look ancient, the rear cable housing looks frayed where it enters the cable stop (missing cap?). Are the brakes even compatible with the brake levers?

Comment: p.s. what is written on the frame is not a sticker. In a moment of inspiration, I think !, the seller felt the need to paint the name Eddy Merckx. The color inspired him

Comment: @Michael: The brakes look like MAFAC brakes, if the levers are road-type, they will be correct. But I have serious doubts about this being a Merckx, the CR doesn't belong indeed. More a donkey trying to pass for a race-horse.

Comment: Now that I think of it, the orange color and pinstripe sticker with world champion colors are common with Crescent. The "CR" points to same direction.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming this is an Eddy Merckx, you can tell a lot about it from its serial number, which should be stamped on the underside of the bottom bracket. There are a few serial-number decoders online. [Here's one](http://www.cadre.org/Merckx/). The one confounding factor is the "CR" seatstay caps. Merckxs usually (but not always) had an "EM" cap. That orange was a popular color for Merckx bikes, but usually there was a blue panel on the downtube, not seat tube, and I don't think they ever were pinstriped.